# Regular expression to find a word starts with & and ends with &

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to replace a word in a url that starts with & and ends with &,but leave one &.
Ex: `url?&name=test&id=2`
Output should be replace `&name=test` with `&newname=againtest i.e url?&newname=againtest&id=2`
Please help me using JS

Comment: You should probably not use regular expressions for this at all.

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner way would be to replace the part that *is surrounded by `&`* and not replace the `&` with it. Lookaround assertions help here:

Replace

```
(?<=&)name=test(?=&)
```

with

```
newname=againtest
```

This can be made more robust as well:

```
(?<=[&?])name=test(?=&|$)
```

to match even in the following examples:

```
url?name=test
url?name=test&foo=bar
url?foo=bar&name=test
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `^([^&]*)(&[^&]+)(&.*)$` with `$1NEWSTRING$3`

See test [here](http://ideone.com/OMqE4).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

```
^\w+\?(&\w+=\w+).*
```

**Explanation:**

`^` Start of line

`\w+`        First word before?

`\?`         Escape ? char as it has special meaning in  regex. We need literal ? char here

`(&\w+=\w+)` Group of keyvalue pair you want to replace after ampersand "& char"

`.*`         Any char after

You can replace the goup we have with the value you want to replace.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = 'url?&name=test&id=2';
var regex = /(.*\?&)name=([^&]*)(&.*)/;
var replacementPattern = '$1newname=again$2$3';
var newUrl = url.replace(regex, replacementPattern);
console.log(newUrl);​​​
```

The above outputs:

```
url?&newname=againtest&id=2
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sLEEQ/)**

To learn more, see [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).